# get the message myLogger.log(e) in a String variable

Tags: java, log4j

I want to get the output of this method myLogger.log(e) in a String variable to be able to test with Junit.

```
myLogger.log(e);
String s= ????
assertEqual(expected,s);
```

Comment: Please give a bit more information about the class that myLogger is for example

Comment: I m using Log4j, it receive a Exception exception as parameters

Comment: Why do you want to test for the log string? This seems quite odd to me, especially since I normally could easly change the log format during deployment. In a unit test you'd normally test the logic and not logging.

Comment: condition is bit unrealistic. can you please explain what is your business requirement?

Comment: I throw a costumized Exception with a customized message, and i want to test fi the message is very well formatted

Comment: Then why don't you unit test the message formatting method?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a log4j appender that writes to a StringWriter. Look at this post:

[How to read log4j output to a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555865/how-to-read-log4j-output-to-a-web-page)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an additional Appender to your Logger. Use a WriterAppender to write to a StringWriter then you change the content of your TextArea to the value of StringWriter#toString()

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("logger");
    Layout layout = new PatternLayout();
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    WriterAppender writerAppender = new WriterAppender(layout, stringWriter);
    logger.addAppender(writerAppender);

    logger.error("test");
    String string = stringWriter.toString();
    System.out.println(string);
  }
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12403701/1515052).