# How to get Logger value in a string array

Tags: java, struts2, log4j

I used the `log4j.Logger` and I have written the log value in to a file using the `FileAppender`.

Now I want to show the log value in a textarea. How can I assign the logger value to an array of Strings?

Comment: what do you wanna show? the stacktrace? or error message?

Comment: i want to show the Level.TRACE

Comment: i do not see a direct way and if you want to show in your application , you can read the file and show it there

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi hahah.. that's right.. this should be the most easy way to do this...

Comment: @praba Not getting clear idea what you exactly want, can you explain more?

Answer (score 15):

You can add an additional `Appender` to your `Logger`. Use a [WriterAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/WriterAppender.html) to write to a `StringWriter` then you change the content of your `TextArea` to the value of `StringWriter#toString()`

Example Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("logger");
    Layout layout = new PatternLayout();
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    WriterAppender writerAppender = new WriterAppender(layout, stringWriter);
    logger.addAppender(writerAppender);
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

    logger.error("test");
    //if(stringWriter changed){// compare to old TextArea-content?
      textArea.setText(stringWriter.toString());
    //}
    //System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
  }
```

you need to find a smart way update your `TextArea` depending on the logLevel and if the content of the `StringWriter` changed.

Update: A comparable solution is presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2555981/1515052).

Comment: stringWriter returns empty value . it is not working.any suggesstions or solutions

Comment: I'm only seeing output from one of the threads. My eclipse console says other threads are logging too, but I'm not seeing their output. Is there a way to capture that, too?

Comment: if i write such a code to create appender on per request basis, and remove when request is server, will this work?

Answer (score 3):

I would write a class that extends [org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.html) and (as the API suggests) override the [append(org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent)](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.html#append%28org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent%29) method. With the [LoggingEvent](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggingEvent.html) you get all necessary information to build the String you want to show. Also you can control where to save those Strings. You wanted to have them in a String array - no problem. If you only want to remember the last n logging events, you could use a queue. 

Here my code (passed a simple test):

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;


public class StringArrayAppender extends AppenderSkeleton{

    private Collection<String> log;

    private int size;

    public StringArrayAppender(int size) {
        this.log = new ArrayDeque<String>(size);
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String[] getLog() {
        return log.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
        // Generate message
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(event.getTimeStamp()).append(": ");
        sb.append(event.getLevel().toString()).append(": ");
        sb.append(event.getRenderedMessage().toString());
        // add it to queue
        if(log.size() == size) {
            ((ArrayDeque<String>) log).removeFirst();
        }
        log.add(sb.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        log = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(log);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return false;
    }
}
```